# How do I convert a WCHAR * to a regular string?

Tags: windows, winapi, casting, wchar

So in Win32 API, I have my main function defined thus:

wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])

I'm passing some arguments to it, and I'd like to execute a switch case based on the value of the argument, something like this.

```
wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* temp = argv[];
    switch (temp) {
    case "one": blah blah;
...
}
```

Of course, the temp=argv[] doesn't work, I'm looking for a suggestion to convert it. Right now I have an if-else-if thing going on, and it's VERY inefficient!

The reason I need to convert it is because I cannot execute a switch case on a WCHAR*.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute a switch on a char* either. (But when you actually need to convert WCHAR* to char*, use WideCharToMultiByte)

You need to use if/else if with [lstrcmpi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647489%28VS.85%29.aspx), [CompareString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317759%28VS.85%29.aspx) or some other string compare function.

Alternatively, use one of the parameter parser libraries like [argtable](http://argtable.sourceforge.net/) or [getopt](http://note.sonots.com/Comp/CompLang/cpp/getopt.html)

Comment: Currently I'm using if/else, but there are 25 conditions and it's extremely inefficient. Also, I'm not allowed to use third party libraries. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you want to use a switch that bad, you could probably hash the input argument and use precomputed hashes for the case statements.

Comment: There's an easier way: ATL conversion macros - T2A()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good idea to do. A WCHAR* could contain unicode characters which cannot be mapped to a char* in a meaningful way.  In case you want to ignore this, there is a forum post at http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=336106 which has some suggestions for converting from WCHAR* to char*.

Comment: The OP's trying to convert ASCII chars into numbers.  He's starting with a WCHAR* for the command line.  It's unlikely he's going to input any Japanese characters to the console!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it from std::wstring to std::string, its easy, maybe there is a shorter way.

Convert WCHAR* to std::wstring using std::wstring constractor, and then use one of std::wstring method to convert to std::String

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example I wrote some time ago.

Create a new win32 console application and select ATL support.  Add this and compile/run...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
// A _TCHAR is a typedef'd, depending on whether you've got a unicode or MBCS build

// ATL Conversion macros are documented here
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.80).aspx
// Declare USES_CONVERSION in your function before using the ATL conversion macros
// e.g. T2A(), A2T()    
USES_CONVERSION;

TCHAR* pwHelloWorld = _T("hello world!");
wcout << pwHelloWorld << endl;

// convert to char
char* pcHelloWorld = T2A(pwHelloWorld);
cout << pcHelloWorld << endl;


cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Of course, you can't switch on a string, but this should give you the info you need in order to read a WCHAR into a char.  From there, you can convert to int easily enough..
Hope this helps ;)